# Not showing the message at all?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my code, it should show the message if the value of Enabled in the table BannerStatus is true, but it does not show it at all
this is my code

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db("induadmi_db");
    $message = mysql_query("SELECT `Message` FROM `Banner`");
    $value = mysql_query("SELECT `Enabled` FROM `BannerStatus`");
     while($msg = mysql_fetch_array($message))
    while($value2 = mysql_fetch_array($value))
 {
    if ($value2['Enabled'] == "true") {
    echo' <div id="emsg" class="emsg_inner emsgB">';
        echo $msg['Message'], "</div>";
}
}
?>
```

Thanks, all help is appreciated greatly!

Comment: are you sure that `Enabled` has value true in database ?

Comment: Yes, I have phpmyadmin opened and I checked

Answer (score 2):

Missing single quote :

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
```

And it is not a very good practice to use `mysql` functions, look forward using `mysqli` or `PDO`.
Also:

```
while($msg = mysql_fetch_array($message)){
   while($value2 = mysql_fetch_array($value)){  
       if ($value2['Enabled'] == 'true') {
          echo "<div id=\"emsg\" class=\"emsg_inner emsgB\">{$msg['Message']}</div>";
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Accidentally deleted it when formatting, it is there in my code though

Comment: @Sam : `var_dump` or `echo` everything you get from the database

Answer (score 1):

Your code fetches the first "message" and then loops through the "values". Is this what you want?

You will not get any values for the next message as the "values" query is already at the last record!

How are these two tables related? Can you join the two tables in one query?

Answer (score 0):

1) Missing brackets `{` and `]`

2) Change this - `echo' <div id="emsg" class="emsg_inner emsgB">';`

Try replacing below code -

```
while($msg = mysql_fetch_array($message))
{
   while($value2 = mysql_fetch_array($value))
   {
      if ($value2['Enabled'] == "true") 
      {
        echo "<div id='emsg' class='emsg_inner emsgB'>";
        echo $msg['Message']. "</div>";
      }
   }
}
```